# Should I drink water during my workout?

Tags: workout, water

When I do my workout, I often feel very thirsty. And I like to drink water after each set of exercises. 
I often drink something around 1.5 liters of water during workout.

Is it okay to drink water in such quantities during workout, or should I wait until the end of the workout?

Comment: What kind of workout would that be @Rogach?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse - Weight-lifting. For about an hour, 4 times a week. And I try to keep the workout intensive and rest only thirty seconds between sets.

Comment: Sip water, don't chug. Your body doesn't absorb water as well if you drink too much too fast. Drink in small sips with breaks in between and only enough until the thirst is satisfied. That way you won't get the waterlogged feeling.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely okay to drink water during a workout! The main concern is to stay hydrated since an athlete that is dehydrated performs poorly.

[The 7 Hydration and Exercise Rules That Every Athlete Needs To Know](http://www.complete-strength-training.com/hydration-and-exercise.html) recommends that you should drink about 600 - 1,200 ml (2.5 - 5 cups) of liquid per hour, which is just below your 1.5 liters that you like to drink.

If you want to drink less during your workout, you could always try to drink more before your training. Try starting to drink some water, every hour starting 2 hours before your workout.

Comment: +1 for drinking more before your training.  I find that staying very hydrated through the day in addition to taking exactly one swallow of water during each pause in my workout is optimal.